# What is the sum of this power series?

Tags: calculus, power-series

This is the series:
$$ \sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac{x^{2n}}{(2+\sqrt{2})^n} $$

My problem is that I don't know how to rid of that $ (2+\sqrt{2})^{-n} $.

Comment: Hint: consider $t=x^2/(2+\sqrt2)$.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**HINT** Let $y = \dfrac{x^2}{2+\sqrt{2}}$ and see what happens.

Comment: Is it really that easy?:))

Answer (score 1):

I recommend using the identities $x^{2n}=(x^2)^n$ and $\dfrac{a^n}{b^n}=\left(\dfrac{a}{b}\right)^n$.